# Transaction never appear on Rinkeby

Tags: etherscan, raw-transaction, sendsignedtransaction, web3.php

I've signed a transaction with my private key and then used the sendRawTransaction function to send the transaction on the network, I got the Transaction Hash, but when I use that transaction has in getTransactionByHash I got empty block hash, block number in the response and transaction never mined.

I'm using web3-php library and implementing it in laravel. Please help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Libraries used:
https://github.com/web3p/web3.php
https://github.com/web3p/ethereum-tx

Here is my code.

```
                $toAddress      = '0x551f7DaFb0569....';
                $fromAccount    = $this->getOwnerAddress();
                
                $from_addr_nonce = "";
                $contract       = $this->getDeployedContract();
                $eth            = $this->getEthObject();
                $eth->getTransactionCount($this->getOwnerAddress(),function($err,$data) use (&$from_addr_nonce){
                    $from_addr_nonce = gmp_intval($data->value);
                });
                $from_addr_nonce = Utils::toHex($from_addr_nonce,true);
                $data     =  "0x".$contract->getData('safeMint', $toAddress, $metadataHash);

                $gasPrice = Utils::toHex(1000);
                $gas      = 10e6;

                $txParams = [
                    'from'      => $fromAccount,
                    'to'        => $this->contractAddress,
                    'value'     => "0x0",
                    'nonce'     => $from_addr_nonce,
                    'gas'       => Utils::toHex($gas,true),
                    'gasPrice'  => $gasPrice,
                    'chainId'   => 4,
                    'data'      => $data,
                ];

                $transaction        = new Transaction($txParams);

                $signedTransaction  = $transaction->sign($this->getprivateKey());

                $eth->sendRawTransaction("0x".$signedTransaction, function ($err, $tx) use (&$nftAddress) {
                    if ($err !== null) {
                        echo "Error: ".$err->getMessage();
                        exit();
                    }
                    $nftAddress = $tx;
                });
```

Comment: Look for your transaction on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io - maybe it's in pending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the transaction library: 
https://github.com/web3p/ethereum-tx.

Use the following library instead.

https://github.com/kornrunner/php-ethereum-offline-raw-tx

It's working fine with me now.

Comment: How do you sign the transaction with php-ethereum-offline-raw-tx?